# Windows 10 Virtual Desktop Hotkeys

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10

Is there a good way to change the hotkeys in windows 10 for the virtual desktop switcher?

My mouse, Logitech MX Performance, SetPoint doesn't support windows key. So i can bind my mouse to have it create a new desktop or switch desktops. Is there a way i can change WIN + SHIFT + D to SHIFT + 1 or some other shift + command?

Comment: You can use a program like AutoHotKeys and create your own hotkey, that maps back, to the actual hotkey.  It is extremely difficult to change the default shortcuts in Windows

Comment: I have been fiddling with auto hotkey but cant figure it out. Especially the 3 key to 1 or 2 keys.

Comment: If your question was what's an AHK script for taking in Shift + 1 and sending WIN + SHIFT + D my answer would be : **+1:: Send #+d::
return**

Comment: Woops, extra colons. Should be **+1:: Send #+d
return**

Comment: ^Numpad3:: Send #^Right return is what i mad to make control plus numpad fire off WIN + CONTROL + RIGHT ARROW. It doesnt work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is!! It's called `zVirtualDesktop`. You can configure the hotkeys any way you'd like. It also has a nice feature called DesktopView which lets you drag and drop your windows across desktops. This view also lets you quickly navigate to any window.

https://github.com/mzomparelli/zVirtualDesktop

Here are some screenshots.

You can choose from several sets of system tray icons that indicate which desktop you are viewing.
[image]

This is DesktopView which lets you move your windows around or navigate to a window.
[image]

In the main settings window you can configure hotkeys and set wallpapers for each desktop
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't really answer your question, but since you are using Logitech mouse (like me) and you are trying to configure SetPoint to switch Windows 10 Virtual Desktop via mouse (like me), then this will help:

[X-Mouse Button Control](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm)

Basically I ditch SetPoint and replaced it with [X-Mouse Button Control](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm), I couldn't be happier!

Logitech is just trying to force us to buy their more expensive mouse for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small tool called "[QuickMouse](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/quickmouse/9nc75895q44l)". With QuickMouse you can switch virtual desktop by just push mouse middle button(wheel) left or right on top of screen. No hotkey needed.

Answer (score 0):

### SetPoint actually supports Windows-Key Mapping, but you have to edit it by hand:

SetPoint saves the settings in a file called "user.xml" located in `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Logitech\SetPoint`

There you can edit the mappings directly and test them after a restart.
The syntax for custom buttons is `^ for Ctrl` `* for Windows Key` and `{KEYNAME}` for all direct keypresses.

So for example to map a Mouse-Button to change virtual desktops you can use the following:

```xml
<Button Number="4" Name="5">
   <Param IconLoc="" Type=""/>
   <Trigger Class="ButtonPress">
      <Param Button="4" EventType="100663297" FirstRepeatDelay="0" RepeatDelay="0" Silent="0" Type="0"/>
      <TriggerState Name="ButtonDownUp" HandlerSet="KeystrokeAssignment">
         <Handler Class="KeyStroke">
            <Param KeyName="^*{LEFT}"/>
         </Handler>
      </TriggerState>
   </Trigger>
</Button>
```

Source: https://tinkertry.com/logitech-multiple-desktop-mouse-mappings-for-windows-10