# windows 10 change virtual desktop hotkeys without external utilities

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

I'm trying to figure out how to change hotkeys for switching virtual desktops on windows 10, I know about AutoHotkey, but I don't want make crutches, may be some register edits or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 Virtual Desktop Hotkeys](https://superuser.com/questions/947869/windows-10-virtual-desktop-hotkeys)